# Tracking motion blurred objects in an image

Tags: opencv, motion-detection, motion-blur, feature-tracking

I an trying to track the location of a moving object in an image. My camera has very low sensitivity, resulting in long exposure times so my object becomes heavily motion-blurred. I am trying to track it with NCC (correlation) using opencv function matchTemplate, with the first un-blurred image as a template, but when the object moves - it almost "disappears", and is untrackable.
Any idea of how I can find any "motion invariants" that remain trackable?

[image: original]

[image: blurred]

added blurred and original. note that the background is sometimes as white as the car...

Comment: Please add few images to illustrate blurred, original etc objects.

Comment: You'll *have* to clean up that blurred image to stand *any* chance of template matching. Even if faster exposure times give less contrast, it would be better than motion blur.

Comment: You mean to "clean up" by shortening the exposure time? sound interesting. I'll check if it's possible in my system. Thanks!